# Static cells - Outlets are always nil

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

It's the first time I use static cells in a table view and I just can't get them to show.

I have two sections (grouped) with two and three cells in each one respectively. The cells are static (custom) and all carry one label and one textfield:

[image]

I have created `IBOutlets` for each textfield, and for each cell in my view controller:

[image]

I have made the link between storyboard -> view controller where the outlets reside:

[image]

I have also set datasource & delegate on `UITableView`:

[image]

Since these are static cells, I am not using dynamic cell-related methods, e.g.`tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`. Instead, I try to reference each textfield and cell via their outlets. My problem is that I keep getting a nil value returned for all the outlets. I tried referencing them in `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` but the result is always nil:

[image]

I programmatically instantiate the UIViewController via the use of a cocoa menu control:

[image]

What on earth am I missing? Any clues?

- Note: I am Swift 2.1, Xcode 7.2

Comment: Have you wired the views in your storyboard to the outlets in your code? Xcode shows a little circle to the left of outlets in your code and if they are wired up the circle will have a dot filling it to let you know. If the circle is empty, then the outlet is not wired.

Comment: Yes, I updated the screenshot to show that.

Comment: Show how you create and navigate to the view controller

Comment: Don't post answers in your question, it makes this post more confusing. Also, keep in mind that the people who answer your questions are investing their time for reputation. If you post the answer in your question you're deterring people from seeing the accepted answer effectively stealing rep from users who invested time.

Comment: If you'd like to answer your own question feel free to post an answer

Comment: Just did that @DanBeaulieu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I wasn't instantiating the UIViewController from the Storyboard.

Before (all outlets were nil):

[image]

After (worked):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is actually obvious. It's like you have not instantiated it. That's why it's all `nil` and you can't use it. Since you are using `Nib` file, you will need to have a way to load the `Nib` file and then reference it. When you are accessing this `UIViewController` from Storyboard, the system will take care this for you. What I am suspecting is, you programmatically create this `UIViewController`.

From another prospective, `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` is not for dynamic cells only. You can pass in the total number of your static cells and you can still use this method to perform the operation you want.

Comment: He's speaking about a storyboard so there is definitely a storyboard. You are probably right about the root cause - creating the controller programatically.

Comment: Hi Lucas, you're right; I am creating the UIViewController programmatically. But I am only using the storyboard, no nib file here. I've updated my Q to show how I instantiate the UIViewController

Comment: I would add and answer but I believe that Lucas is correct, you need to setup the data source delegate methods to populate the table view even if you have outlets to them.  ViewDidLoad and viewDidAppear, etc, are calls for when the view of the view controller itself are ready for display, not the table view.  The table view then needs to go through its preparation and if you are dynamically putting data into it, you do that through cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: If you are programmatically creating the view controller then I think you need to use a nib file. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/initWithNibName:bundle:) says "When using a storyboard to define your view controller and its associated views, you never initialize your view controller class directly." So the views are not getting loaded and that's why they are nil.

Comment: Lucas, your comment just pointed me to the right direction. You were right, I was not instantiating from the Storyboard. I updated my Q with what I did exactly. It worked like a charm after that. Many thanks.

Comment: If you create the view controller programatically, you should instantiate your UI element in the `-init()`. I am happy it helps.

Comment: @Sulthan he did not mention he used Storyboard, it might be a .xib file